# Parsing specific elements of a String in Java

Tags: java

I want to read Object from string expression. eg:

I have following string:

```
(3:2,1)
```

or

```
(3:null,1)
```

now I want to read `Object1=3; Object2=2; Object3=1` or

`Object1=3; Object2=null; Object3=1`.

How can I read it in Java.

Comment: What is/should be the type of these Objects? And do you already have the `Object1`, `Object2` , etc?

Comment: Based on your provided string, use ArrayList<Integer>, parse your string, convert each token to Integer and add it in arraylist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am usually not a big fan of regular expressions, but this is a perfect example of where the proper application of a regular expression is simpler and most importantly easier to maintain than other String manipulation based solutions.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Parser
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final String s1 = "(3:2,1)";
        final String s2 = "(3:null,1)";
        final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\((\\d+):(\\d+|null),(\\d+)\\)");
        final Matcher m1 = p.matcher(s1);
        m1.matches();
        System.out.format("Object1=%s; Object2=%s; Object3=%s", m1.group(1), m1.group(2), m1.group(3));
        System.out.println();
        final Matcher m2 = p.matcher(s2);
        m2.matches();
        System.out.format("Object1=%s; Object2=%s; Object3=%s", m2.group(1), m2.group(2), m2.group(3));
    }
}
```

As per your requirements the expected output looks like

```
Object1=3; Object2=2; Object3=1
Object1=3; Object2=null; Object3=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, this is what you want:

```
String s[] = inputString.substring(1, inputString.length() - 2)split(","); // inputString is your string expression
Object object3 = s[1]; 
String s1[] = s[0].split(":");
Object object1 = s1[0];
Object object2 = s1[1];
```

If you want `null` instead of the string `"null"`, you could add a check as this :

```
Object object2 = s1[1].equals("null") ? null : s1[1];
```

and similarly convert (parse) to integer if you want:

```
Object object2 = s1[1].equals("null") ? null : new Integer(s1[1]);
```

Comment: This won't get rid of the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

you can parse the string with substring
http://www.roseindia.net/help/java/s/java-substring.shtml

i would think u could do object1 = string
but really you would normally do
object1.variable = string

otherwise its not an "object"
its a "string object"

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "3:2,1";
String str2 = "3:null,1";

// first case
Object[] objects = str.split(":|,");
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(objects));

// second case
Object[] objects2 = str2.split(":|,");
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(objects2));
```